# Using Require.js without data-main

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Can I use Require.js in development without using the `data-main` attribute to load in my initial script? ie. `<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>` I'm finding it difficult for me to work with this attribute in my development environment.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yep, take a look at the documentation: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

You need to call require.config() and set baseUrl.  Based on your example:

```
<script src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({
        baseUrl: "scripts"
    });

    require( [ /*...*/ ], function(  /*...*/ ) {
        /*...*/
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's a convenient way to use requireJS in a valid xhtml page as far as `data-main` was only introduced into html5.

Comment: Just to be clear about @Charles-EdouardCoste comment, `data-main` is not an html5 property. Html5 simply allows `data-*` properties. `Data-main` is specifically searched for by require.js, i.e. here: https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/blob/4316f8f19f981c726eb32b5335c36237e0125948/require.js#L2016

Comment: Yes, I was just fast-typing. Indeed, I would have written "data-*"